# Explain the lack of commas in James Joyce's "The Dead"

Tags: style, technique

I am closely reading/editing (for my own benefit) the text of *Dubliners*, the collection of short stories written by James Joyce.

In some stories, such as *The Dead*, there are many instances of what you might call run-on sentences, with little or no commas. Here's a shining example (taken from *The Dead*):

> Mary Jane waited on her pupils and saw that they got the best slices and Aunt Kate and Aunt Julia opened and carried across from the piano bottles of stout and ale for the gentlemen and bottles of minerals for the ladies.

This text is taken from Project Gutenberg. It matches a Penguin edition I have, which in turn is taken from a critical edition by Scholes and Litz. (You can also view the first edition [here](https://archive.org/details/dubliners00joyc_8/page/n247/mode/2up) at archive.org.)

To my brain, the text seems to require at least one comma, after *the best slices*.

Here's a second, more egregious example (also taken from *The Dead*):

> Her blue felt hat would show off the bronze of her
> hair against the darkness and the dark panels of her skirt would show
> off the light ones.

In my opinion, the above text needs a comma after *against the darkness*. The reason is that it's ambiguous without it.

My question is this: is this really Joyce's intention, or is it a mistake in the typesetting?

If it is indeed his intention, then what effect is he trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Writing. This question is asking about a literary work, rather than how to help your own writing craft. It's a good question, but you've asked it on the wrong site. Since we're limited in the sites we can migrate a question to, you should delete the question here, and ask it at our other Stack Exchange site, [literature.se]. For further guidance about our Writing site, see [ask] and take the site's  [Tour]. :-)

Comment: I tried to delete the question. The system doesn't allow it.

Comment: Yes, my apology, I should have noticed that answers had already been posted when I made my suggestion. You can't delete a question once it has been answered. It's why some sites tend to downvote answers to off-topic questions. This Writing site is a bit gentler on contributors. Did you post the question on [Lit.SE]? You'll get better answers there.

Comment: No, I haven't posted on the other site. I'm satisfied with the answers here.

Comment: I don’t think much of either answer. Joyce’s style in *Dubliners* is not really “quirky”, and both answers overlook an alternative explanation: that the omission of the comma in each case was consistent with the editing style of the *publisher.* On our **Writing** site, I’d have expected someone to have made the obvious point that Joyce may not have had much sway over his editor at that relatively early stage in his career. On our **Literature** site, there’d be a greater chance that someone could identify whether that punctuation was in Joyce’s manuscript or was a decision by his editor. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James Joyce is an author that has an extremely unique grammatical style, so this is just part of his style, not a typesetting mistake. He was a Modernist, meaning that [he experimented heavily with structure, dialogue and other traditional pillars of writing](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-styles-four-writers-their-writtings-james-378589), and wasn't afraid to challenge the norms of literature in his time, hence why his writing often comes across as odd and disorganized at first glance. He's a bit of an acquired taste, to say the least! This is why he uses a lot of strange sentence structures and run-on sentences - it's because he is trying to get outside the box, in a sense, and push the boundaries of what writing actually is. (Of course, people heavily differ on whether they actually *like* his writing, and I absolutely respect you if it's not your thing.)

Other authors that have unique styles like this include [Cormac McCarthy, who wrote *The Road* without quotation marks or apostrophes](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/why-cormac-mccarthy-does-not-add-punctuation-other-37763). This can come across as equally jarring if you're not used to his style of writing.

> Just remember that the things you put into your head are there forever, he said. You might want to think about that.
>
> You forget some things, dont you?
>
> Yes. You forget what you want to remember and you remember what you want to forget.

[Other examples](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-authors-with-the-most-unique-and-strange-writing-styles).

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was his quirky style.
Do not know of any official English department position on that usage of commas.

Comment: It's a common convention to add a comma when clauses separated by "and" have different subjects. The University of Oxford Style Guide 2016, on page 12 ("Comma"), says that main clauses should be separated either by a semi-colon, or by a comma followed by a co-ordinating [sic] conjunction. Our sister site [ELU.SE] will almost certainly have some expert opinion on this point.